# Jquery .width() returns 0 zero before appending the image to the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, width

I'm using jquery and i'm trying to create a slideshow.

**Before i append the image**, i shall know **the Width of the image**.
So i use *.width()* of jquery and *.attr("width").*

My **code** is as follows:

```
var attr_href = $next.attr('href'); /*returns the href of the image*/
var $item = $('<img src="'+attr_href+'" />'); 

//$item contains the image, the image is not displayed to the browser yet!!!

var itemWidth = $item.width();
alert(itemWidth); 
// --->  returns zero 0 in Mozilla and in IE

var itemWidth2 = $item.attr("width");
alert(itemWidth2);
//In Mozilla, the first time it returns 0.After the image is loaded, it returns the right Width
//In IE, always returns 0 zero !!!

//Now i have to append the photo and i have to use the right Width of the image!!!
var final_img = $('<img src="'+attr_href+'" width="'+itemWidth+'"/>');
$('.SlideShow').append(final_img);
```

So, i tried to use the **.load()** and i did:

```
var attr_href = $next.attr('href'); /*returns the href of the image*/
var $item = $('<img src="'+attr_href+'" />'); 

//$item contains the image, the image is not displayed to the browser yet!!!

$item.load(function  () {
    var WidthAfterLoading = $item.attr("width");
    var WidthAfterLoading2 = $item.width();

});

alert(WidthAfterLoading);  //returns "undefined" in both IE and Mozilla
alert(WidthAfterLoading2); //returns "undefined" in both IE and Mozilla
```

So, before i append the image to the browser, i shall know the right width of the image.
But i get zero(0) and undefined.

Is there any other way, in order to take the **right width of the image??**

Thanks, in advance

Comment: There is no `width` attribute

Comment: I apologize, I was thinking that `$item` was the `a` tag.

Answer (score 7):

Ah, I had the same problem before.

```
<img id="someImage"></img>
```

Then in your JQuery

```
$("#someImage").attr("src", "url/to/img").load(function() {  
    var width = $(this).width();
    // do stuff!
});
```

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf6Fk/) of course!

Comment: Thanks, i still get 0 zero.Even when the image is loaded, i get zero again.I don't know what i shall do...

Comment: Try out your code on a fiddle and paste it here so we can take a look at what's going on :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the elements do not attach to the DOM tree
try to attach the elements to the DOM before invoking .width()